# create scroll-able rectangles from items in a list

Tags: python, pygame

I Have a program where it has a list of names. I want to be able to list each of these names onto a rectangle. I want each name to create its own rectangle. This example create a rectangle for each title in the list i put `''` at the start of the list as I got an error saying I couldn't divide by zero in python by adding `''` fixed that.

```
import pygame

width,height = 800,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

mover = 0
games = ['','Space Invaders','Snake']
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 4:
                if mover > 0:
                    mover -= 15
            if event.button == 5:
                if mover < (height-120)-60:
                    mover += 15
    screen.fill((47,79,79))
    for game in games:
        for num in range(len(games)):
            if num != 0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,51,51), (100,((height-120)/num)-mover,width-200,20))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,51,51), (width-30,100,25,height-120)) #SCROLL BAR
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (width-29,mover+100,23,60)) #SCROLLING BAR
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (0,0,0), (0,100),(width,100), 4)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I am not sure in how I can get the rectangles closer together so that there is only 5 to 10 pixels between each rectangle. I also feel like there is a better way in doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a distance to top of the screen. e.g. 100. Define a distance between the lines. The height of a line is 20. If the gap between the lines should be 10, the the distance is 30. So the start of a line is `110 + num*30 - mover`:

```py
for num, game in enumerate(games):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,51,51), (100, 110 + num*30 + mover, width-200, 20))
```

Note, you can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), to get tuples of list index and list element.

Comment: Now that I think about it I don't know why I tried dividing, not the best at math